KLN 900 GPS unit not loading
I have been trying to update KLN 900 database using the usb cable however getting the msg "Data Loader not ready" on KLN unit and on laptop screen "Not responding" with data-loading not moving past 0%. I have tried to trouble shoot as per the guidelines of Honeywell, still no joy. I have connected PL-2303 USB to serial adapter and P/N050-03213-0000 loader. Still not able to update the existing card.Com port 4 is being used.Can anyone help through this??

Welcome Kunal!  Please find appropriate tags for your question.  FYI, the software-rec tag is not appropriate for this question. Also, you'll want to read the help pages to ensure your question is on-topic.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

It's vaguely on topic here but I wonder if aviation is a better home for it.

I think it can be on topic. OPs not really asking about a software rec. They've got a peripheral connected to their computer that isn't talking. We just need more info about how the connection is configured, the device's requirements, ets.

@music2myear, I have connected PL-2303 USB to serial adapter and P/N050-03213-0000 loader. Still not able to update the existing card. Have tried all trouble shooting given by Bendix king, still no joy. Still flying on old database

That information needs to be in the main question. If you think of more information that helps make the question better and more complete, use the EDIT button and add it to the main question. A significant part of getting good answers on this site is having a fully detailed question, and editing your question to improve it is strongly recommended.
